# file_exists() постоянно возвращает false

Tags: php, file-exists

Все варианты были перепробованы, постоянно возвращает `false`; `safe_mode = Off`. В чём может быть ошибка?

```
<?php
$home = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    //$fileName =  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/php12/" . $_POST['name'];
    if (file_exists($_POST['name'])) {
        echo "Файл $fileName существует";
        $openFile = fopen($_POST['name'], 'r');
        while (!feof($openFile)) {
            $text = fgets($openFile);
            echo $text . "<br>";
        }
        fclose($openFile);
    }
    else echo "Файл $fileName не существует";
}
?>
```

Comment: `safe_mode boolean ... Внимание. Данная возможность была помечена УСТАРЕВШЕЙ начиная с версии PHP 5.3.0 и была УДАЛЕНА в версии PHP 5.4.0.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

потому что у Вас нету файла по указанному пути!
Отталкивайтесь от `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` - она указывает на корневую директорию Вашего проекта (если конечно ее не испортили настройками сервера).

Вот это

```
file_exists($_POST['name'])
```

проверяет наличие указанного файла, начиная от директории, где размещен файл текущего скрипта.

Поэтому проверяйте куда указывает `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` и стройте от него путь к файлу, как вы делали в закомментированной строке

```
$fileName =  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/php12/" . $_POST['name'];
if (file_exists( $fileName )) {...}
```

При этом `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` должно возвращать примерно такое значение: `/var/www/your_project_name`

Comment: Оказалось, что проблема в кодировке (в названиях файлах).
Но спасибо, Вы оказались правы